# Shadow can't be added in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, layer

The goal is to add a shadow line along the left side of the navigation controller's view, can be seen when the view is sliding to the right.

But the same code (both version 1 and 2) works on iOS 6 and 5.

All code is placed in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

### Version 1

```
CALayer *navigationViewLayer = [[[self navigationController] view] layer];
CGPathRef path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:[[[self navigationController] view] bounds]] CGPath];
[navigationViewLayer setShadowPath:path];
[navigationViewLayer setShouldRasterize:YES]; // rasterize save the effort of drawing every time by caching
[navigationViewLayer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]]; // Have to set rasterization scale for retina screen
[navigationViewLayer setMasksToBounds:NO];
[navigationViewLayer setShadowRadius:5.0f];
[navigationViewLayer setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
[navigationViewLayer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[navigationViewLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
```

### Version 2

```
CGRect screenBoundsRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
rect.origin.x = -4; // SHADOW_LINE_WIDTH
rect.origin.y = 0;
rect.size.width = 4; // SHADOW_LINE_WIDTH
rect.size.height = screenBoundsRect.size.height;
UIImageView *shadowLineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
[gradient setFrame:[shadowLineImageView bounds]];
[gradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)]; // default to (0.5, 0.0)
[gradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)]; // default to (0.5, 1.0)
[gradient setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:140/255.f green:140/255.f blue:140/255.f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                                              (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:189/255.f green:189/255.f blue:189/255.f alpha:0.0f] CGColor], nil]]; // color RGB values are optimized by test
[[shadowLineImageView layer] insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[shadowLineImageView setAlpha:1.0f];
[[[self navigationController] view] addSubview:shadowLineImageView];
[shadowLineImageView autorelease];
```

#### Screenshots

**Figure 1. Version 1 works on iOS 6 simulator:**

[image]

**Figure 2. Version 1 works on iOS 5 iPhone 4:**

[image]

**Figure 3. Version 1 doesn't work on iOS 7 simulator:**

[image]

**Figure 4. Version 2 works on iOS 6 simulator:**

[image]

**Figure 5. Version 2 works on iOS 5 iPhone 4:**

[image]

**Figure 6. Version 2 doesn't work on iOS 7 simulator:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by placing the above code (both version 1 and version 2 works) in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` method anywhere after calling `[super viewDidLoad];` for iOS 7, 6 and 5.

Placing the above code into `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`  only works for iOS 6 and 5.

#### Screenshots

When placing the above code in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` method anywhere after calling `[super viewDidLoad];`,

**Version 1 now works on iOS 7 simulator**

[image]

**Version 2 now works on iOS 7 simulator**

[image]